# GFortran doesn't know system()

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to execute a command in Fortran and because our cluster uses old Compilers I can't use execute_command_line. Therefore I'm trying to switch to system:

```
    succ = system("zip -0q " // zipfile &
                             // " " // npy_name)
    if(succ /=  0) then
        write (*,*) "Can't execute zip command"
    endif
```

For IFort I can use:

```
    USE IFPORT
```

and it works fine. GFortran doesn't know this library (because it's intels) so I comment it out and then I get:

```
~/NPY-for-Fortran/src/npy.f90:52:15:

         succ = system("rm " // npy_name)
               1
Error: Function ‘system’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

How can I execute commands in the command line, such that it works on old & new compilers, as well as Intel & GNU? If you need a full working environment, this is the whole sourcefile:

https://github.com/MRedies/NPY-for-Fortran.git

Comment: I have always used it as a subroutine, `call system(..)`.  FWIW.

Comment: @agentp -- you can "call" it, or you can use it as a function to return the return value of the system command.

Comment: You have to go back to gfortran 4.1 before having `system` not available.  Supporting a version that old/limited wouldn't be high on my list of priorities.

Comment: Per current docs it can be used either way, but I don't know if that was always the case for old compilers.    `ifort` does not require the `USE IFPORT` if you use the subroutine form by the way.

Comment: Without USE IFPORT my ifort version 17.0.4 does not compile it.

Comment: Without IFPORT you can use the *subroutine* version, that is, `use system(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

system is a part of the GNU extension standard in GFortran, so you have to be using that standard (and not std=f95, for instance).

```
gfortran -std=gnu file.f90
```

Comment: Which is the default.

Comment: Are you even sure that std=f95 will remove it? Extension intrinsics are not against the standard, they are allowed.

Comment: Yeah, and since he didn't show his compiler call, I'm assuming his call (or his environment) changes that default.

Comment: And no, I'm not "sure" it will solve the problem. It's just the most obvious tack.

Comment: It did solve the problem. I had -std=f2008 and now it works. Thanks